# Getting correct search result page numbers- Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, while-loop

I am trying to get correct page number for Seattle which is 7 and then click on every pages from 1 to 7. I have 2 problems see the parts with asterisk ** below:

1) I am not sure how to write the xpath so that I get 7 instead of 11

2) The while loop is an infinite loop

```
public class Job {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Shahriar\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://web.expeditors.com/careers/#/listTop");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //Disable the cookie notification at bottom
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='hs-eu-decline-button']")).click();

        // Find more cities and scroll down
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='moreCity']")).click();
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,5500)", "");

        //Locate US-Seattle and click and verify
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='ng-binding']//input[@id='us~Seattle']")).click();
        String state=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'United States - Seattle')]")).getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(state, "United States - Seattle");

        **//Number of search pages found should be 7
         List<WebElement> resultPages=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@href='#listTop']"));
        Assert.assertEquals(7, resultPages.size());**

        **//Go to each page by clicking on page number at bottom
        int count=0;
        WebElement next_button=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@ng-click='setCurrent(pagination.current + 1)']"));
        while (resultPages.size()!=0){
            next_button.click();
            count++;
            System.out.println("Current page is "+ count);                  
        }**
        //driver.close();
    }
}
```

I could use some help. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the logic that you need.

```
//Number of search pages found should be 7
     List<WebElement> resultPages=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@href='#listTop' and @ng-click='setCurrent(pageNumber)']"));
    Assert.assertEquals(7, resultPages.size());

    for (int i = 1; i <= resultPages.size(); i++) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@href='#listTop' and @ng-click='setCurrent(pageNumber)'])[" + i +"]")).click();
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@href='#listTop' and @ng-click='setCurrent(pageNumber)'])[" + i +"]")).getText());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have 1 question. What is [" + i +"]")-- doing?

Comment: `i` is the index here, as there are 7 page links we are selecting each of them based on the index so we wrapped the common xpath which will match all 7 page links and then getting only the specified index with `i`. Hope that's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is counting pages, but the condition itself appears to be static (I can't tell without the actual page).  You probably want something more like

```
        int count=0;
        WebElement next_button=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@ng-click='setCurrent(pagination.current + 1)']"));
        while (next_button != null){
            next_button.click();
            count++;
            System.out.println("Current page is "+ count); 
            next_button=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@ng-click='setCurrent(pagination.current + 1)']"));                 
        }
```

As for your 7 vs 11 result pages, again it's hard to tell without the HTML, but your XPath search is for `By.xpath("//a[@href='#listTop']")` so I'd check and see what's in your HTML with `listTop`.  Perhaps other elements are somehow using that anchor tag?

Comment: The count did not work, still infinite loop. Thanks.